# How can I return tabular string data from a dynamic Entity Framework stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I threw together a prototype application using hand rolled ADO connections rather than EF, and I'm now "upgrading". One of my stored procedures looks like this:

```
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(999);

SELECT @tableName = DatabaseTable
FROM JobQueue
WHERE JobId = @JobId;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(999);

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName;

EXEC (@sql);
```

Now, EF isn't going to know anything about the table in this instance. It might have any number of columns of any data type at all. It can't be mapped to an entity because it's dynamic and won't exist any more once this job is finished. So the query has to be dynamic and that also means I can't generate a return type in EF either.

My original ADO code just grabbed the data and read it into a `List<string[]>` like this:

```
List<string[]> result = new List<string[]>();
while (dr.Read())
{
    string[] values = new string[dr.FieldCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        values[i] = dr[i].ToString();
    }
    result.Add(values);
}
```

And that was fine. But I can't work out how to get EF to do something similar. The closest I've got is this:

```
var query = Entities.Database
            .SqlQuery<List<string>>("exec spGetJobData @JobId", new SqlParameter("JobId", jobId))
            .ToList();
```

Which returns the expected number of items in the List, but all of them are empty.

How do I get my data?

Comment: EF is not geared to do what you are asking. You could explicitly tell it what type to map the result to and it could do it for one type, but not for a variety of types. You'll have to choose between keeping your code and it's "dynamic" nature. or rewriting it to use strongly typed entities.

Comment: Just leave your ADO implementation (but use Entities.Database.Connection). It won't be any worse than doing the same via SqlQuery.

Comment: @Theo sorry, I didn't make that clear. I'm happy to treat everything as a string in this case. Or to put it another way, I don't care what the data types in the original table are, for my purposes they can all be represented as strings. But obviously they'll need to be a List<string[]> or a list of lists or somesuch.

Comment: @MattThrower I understood that, but EF can't do what you want. You'll either have to rewrite it to use EF types, or leave your implementation as is.

Comment: @Theo - just FYI, if you want to compile your comments into a short answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @MattThrower - Thanks. Sorry for the delay,  I have been away for a while.

Comment: Stored procedure + dynamic results = [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF will want to have strongly defined types for all database returns, and will only allow 1-to-1 mapping. So the short answer is EF will not support what you want. It seems your options are to either re-write your code to use EF or keep it as-is.